# how can i make the navbar items invisible in bootstrap 5 until screen reaches a certain width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am making a navbar using bootstrap 5 and want to make the navbar items invisible until the screen size is below a certain width.

Comment: It's explained clearly in the [Bootstrap Navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#responsive-behaviors)

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries in css.

```css
div {
  display: none;
  background: red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<div>
    You cant see me on big screens
</div>
```

Sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtq3gxb5/).

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the first navbar's html on [this page of Bootstrap v5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/), for an in detail example. Basically you would be required to add a class `navbar-expand-lg` (you can use any size acronym of bootstrap in place of `lg`) to your `nav`. And put all your navbar items in a `div` with classes `collapse navbar-collapse`.